# Maximum area with a given perimeter

Tags: geometry

An arbitrary pentagon (which is convex) is given to you, and it has a perimeter of $k$. Determine the 
i) maximum area, rigorously, in terms of $k$.
ii) maximum INTEGRAL area, in terms of $k$.

Comment: Is it that u want to know when the area can be maximum? if so its in the case of a regular pentagon and is given by {n(l^2)}/4tan(180/n) where n is number of sides and t is length of each side so nt=k

Comment: How rigorously? If we *assume* that there *is* a pentagon of perimeter $k$ which has maximum area, showing that this optimal pentagon is regular is not difficult.  However, although the *existence* of an optimal pentagon is intuitively reasonable, *proving* it rigorously takes quite a bit of  effort.

Comment: *Among all $n$-gons inscribed in a circle, which one has largest area  and which one has largest perimeter? The regular polygon is the expected answer, and this turns out to be the case.*

Maxima and minima without calculus by Ivan Morton Niven Volume 6, 6.1 Introduction.